# Google Stackdriver - how can I use my Kubernetes YAML labels for Stackdriver Log Query?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

When using Google Stackdriver I can use the log query to find the exact log statements I am looking for.

This might look like this:

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
resource.labels.project_id="my-project"
resource.labels.location="europe-west3-a"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster"
resource.labels.namespace_name="dev"
resource.labels.pod_name="my-app-pod-7f6cf95b6c-nkkbm"
resource.labels.container_name="container"
```

However as you can see in this query argument `resource.labels.pod_name="my-app-pod-7f6cf95b6c-nkkbm"` that I am looking for a pod with the id `7f6cf95b6c-nkkbm`. Because of this I can not use this Stackdriver view with this exact query *if* I deployed a new revision of `my-app` therefore having a new ID and the one in the curreny query becomes *invalid* or not locatable.

Now I don't always want to look for the new ID every time I want to have the current view of my `my-app` logs. So I tried to add a special label `stackdriver: my-app` to my Kubernetes YAML file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        stackdriver: my-app <<<
```

Revisiting my newly deployed Pod I can assure that the label `stackdriver: my-app` is indeed existing.

Now I want to add this new label to use as a query argument:

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
resource.labels.project_id="my-project"
resource.labels.location="europe-west3-a"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster"
resource.labels.namespace_name="dev"
resource.labels.pod_name="my-app-pod-7f6cf95b6c-nkkbm"
resource.labels.container_name="container"
resource.labels.stackdriver=my-app <<< the kubernetes label
```

As you can guess this did not work otherwise I'd have no reason to write this question ;)
Any idea how the thing I am about to do can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea how the thing I am about to do can be achieved?

Yes! In fact, I've prepared an example to show you the whole process :)

Let's assume:

- You have a `GKE` cluster named: `gke-label`
- You have a Cloud Operations for GKE enabled (logging)
- You have a `Deployment` named `nginx` with a following `label`:

  - `stackdriver: look_here_for_me`

`deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      stackdriver: look_here_for_me
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        stackdriver: look_here_for_me
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

You can apply this definition and send some traffic from the other pod so that the logs could be generated. I've done it with:

- `$ kubectl run -it --rm --image=ubuntu ubuntu -- /bin/bash`
- `$ apt update && apt install -y curl`
- `$ curl NGINX_POD_IP_ADDRESS/NONEXISTING` # <-- this path is only for better visibility

After that you can go to:

- `GCP Cloud Console (Web UI)` -> `Logging` (I used new version)

With the following query:

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="gke-label"
-->labels."k8s-pod/stackdriver"="look_here_for_me"
```

You should be able to see the container logs as well it's `label`:

[image: NGINX_POD]

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! However I also found out it's simpler to use the query instead. I don't need to care about those random pod IDs because I can do a query like this: `resource.labels.pod_name:"logistic-gate" `. Omitting the ID and using `:` as operator is like a `contains()` for the query